# Difference between とあれば、にあって、とあって

Tags: jlpt

Can someone please explain the difference between

- **とあれば**
- **にあって**
- **とあって**

I've read the explanation from my 新完全マスター book but I'm afraid I don't fully understand the difference in nuance between these grammatical patterns.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 「～～**と**あれば」= "***if*** it is for ~~".  Think of it as an emphatic form of 「なら」.

「よし[子]{こ}のためとあれば、[死]{し}んでもかまわない。」 = "I would not mind dying it it were for Yoshiko."

You can insert 「もし」 at the beginning of the sentence if you want to.

Occasionally, you will encounter the literary form 「～～とあ**ら**ば」.  The form "--**a**ba", instead of "--**e**ba" is heavily used in set phrases such as 「急{いそ}がば回{まわ}れ」 ("Slow and steady wins the race.").

> 「～～**に**あって」= "during ~~", "in the condition of ~~"  Think of it as an emphatic form of 「に」.

「この[非常時]{ひじょうじ}にあっても、キミ子は[冷静]{れいせい}だった。」= "Even during this emergency, Kimiko was calm."

> 「～～**と**あって」= "because of ~~", "due to the fact that ~~", etc.  It expresses the specialness of the occasion.

「５[年]{ねん}に[一度]{いちど}のお[祭]{まつ}りとあって、[誰]{だれ}もが[興奮]{こうふん}していた。」 = "Because it was a once-in-every-five-years festival, everyone was excited."

Comment: This is a very good explanation, thanks. The exact phrase that stumped me was 出世のため＿＿＿どんなことでもするという人達がいるのだ。In this case, I felt that putting とあれば and とあって both worked well.