# What form is 急がば in 急がば回れ?

Tags: meaning, verbs, proverbs

What form is this. how do you use it and is it only used for proverbs? The closest I know for the verb Isogu is Isoganai or Isogeba, but not Isogaba.

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/52173/%e5%af%84%e3%82%89%e3%81%b0-from-%e5%af%84%e3%82%89%e3%81%b0%e5%a4%a7%e6%a8%b9%e3%81%ae%e9%99%b0

Comment: Also, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25247/difference-between-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%82%e3%82%8c%e3%81%b0-%e3%81%ab%e3%81%82%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%82%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6/25251#25251